# Non standard way of calling sub-routines in Perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am trying a different way of calling a subroutine in a Perl script.

I have a set of functions as follows:

```
sub Testcase_CheckStatus {
    print "TestCase_CheckStatus called\n";
}
```

Then I'm traversing a Perl hash with keys like "CheckStatus":

```
while (my ($k, $v) = each %test_cases) {
    print "TestCase_$k","\n";
    Testcase_$k();
}
```

Basically, I want to call the function Testcase_CheckStatus like above while parsing the keys of hash, but I'm getting this error:

> Can't locate object method "Testcase_" via package "CheckStatus" (perhaps you forgot to load "CheckStatus"?) at ./main.pl line 17

What can I do to correct this problem? Is there any alternate way of doing the same?

Comment: Note that this is unallowed under "strict" mode for a reason. Building up functions or variable names at runtime is dangerous and fragile. wk's solution (using a hash of anonymous functions) on the other hand gives exactly the same result, and is both safe and perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: Important background reading: "Why it's stupid to use a variable as a variable name" ([part 1](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html), [part 2](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html), and [part 3](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html)) by Mark Dominus, author of the excellent [*Higher Order Perl*](http://hop.perl.plover.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should allow you to do what you want:

```
while (my ($k, $v) = each %test_cases) {
    print "TestCase_$k","\n";
    &{"Testcase_$k"}();
}
```

However, this won't work if `strict` is in use.  If you are using `strict` you will need a `no strict` inside the while loop, e.g.:

```
while (my ($k, $v) = each %test_cases) {
    no strict 'refs';

    print "TestCase_$k","\n";
    &{"Testcase_$k"}();
}
```

Comment: This is unidiomatic and prone to possible command injections if the programmer is not careful with data supplied from the outside. I can't recommend it. - wk.'s answer shows a dispatch table; that solution should be used in the majority of cases.

Comment: `no strict ...` almost equals "Let's Do It The Wrong Way".  I mean, it can be used as hack in many cases, but generally it indicates that wrong approach is being taken.  If yo must, do it, but at least build a moat of warning comments around it.

Comment: You are both correct, I wouldn't do it like this myself but it is the direct answer to the OP's question of how to call a function given part of the function name in a string.

Comment: @mttrb It is a direct and useful answer, alghough it is the less correct one. (With respect that the OP is open to alternatives.) It's just that we'd rather like the other one accepted :)

Answer (score 13):

Other way:

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use strict;


my $testcases = {
    test_case_1 => sub {
        return 1 * shift();
    },
    test_case_2 => sub {
        return 3 * shift();
    },
    test_case_3 => \&SomeSub,
};

for (1 .. 3) {
    say $testcases->{ 'test_case_' . $_ }(7);
}


sub SomeSub {
    return 5 * shift();
}
```

Comment: It's usually called a "Dispatch Table".